# sed 's/-\([0-9.]\+\)/(\1)/g' inputfile what does this command mean?

Tags: sed

I am trying to find out what the following command means:

```
sed 's/-\([0-9.]\+\)/(\1)/g' inputfile
```

I know it has to do with non-digit characters.

Comment: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/

Answer (score 12):

In GNU sed, it looks for a dash followed by some digits or dots, and replaces that with the same digits in parenthesis. That is, it turns `-123.45` into `(123.45)`.

In some other `sed`s, like the BSD-based one on macOS, it looks for a dash, a digit or dot, and a literal plus sign, and then removes the dash and surrounds the rest in parenthesis. That is, it turns `-1+` into `(1+)`, but leaves stuff like `-123` as-is.

---

The difference is because `\+` does not have a standard meaning in basic regular expressions. GNU interprets it as the same as `+` in extended regexes, i.e. "one or more of the previous", while others take it as literal `+`.

As for the other parts in the left-hand pattern, the dash matches itself, `[0-9.]` matches any one digit or dot, and the `\( .. \)` capture the part in between. In the replacement, the parenthesis are literal, and `\1` puts back whatever was within the `\( .. \)`.

More portably, that should be either

- in extended RE, assuming your `sed` supports `-E`, which many do:

  ```
  sed -E 's/-([0-9.]+)/(\1)/'
  ```
- in basic RE:

  ```
  sed 's/-\([0-9.]\{1,\}\)/(\1)/'
  ```

Both should replace a dash in front of a number with parenthesis around it.

Comment: Thanks. The \+ meant to me to escape the plus sign, not the 1 or more meaning.

Comment: Note that while `sed -E` is probably going to be specified in the next major version of the POSIX standard, it's still not, and it's still not supported on many commercial Unices. There are also still systems out there with older versions of GNU or busybox `sed` supporting `sed -r` for that but not `-E` yet. So it's a bit early to say it's _portable_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, ah right, sorry. fixed that first one. IIRC GNU `sed` supports `-E` as an undocumented feature since a long time. I have some GNU `sed` dated 2009, where `-E` works. That seems like a reasonable time to say it's probably ok by now (on GNU).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it changing the format of negative numbers from having a `-` in front of them to instead being surrounded by parentheses.

It searches for a sequence that starts with `-` followed by a sequence of numerals and decimals `[0-9.]` being a match to numerals and decimals, and `\+` modifying it to match one or more such character in a sequence.  The sequence of numerals and decimals are inside `\(...\)`, which is the first expression, and in the replacement clause, `(\1)` will paste the first expression between `()`.  End result is removal of a negative sign in front of a number and wrapping it in parentheses.

So with an input of:

```
test value: -123.4
```

the output should be of the form

```
test value: (123.4)
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I did miss that.  I'll edit it in.